# How to use Strings in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm trying to use a different `String`, for each item in the `RecyclerView`, but my program always takes the first `String` I've put in the `ArrayList`, no matter which item I click on:

```
   @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
       final View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);
        final ContentMain contentMain = mData.get(viewType);

              v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
              
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), contentMain.getMyContent(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
             }    
    
        ViewHolder vHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ContentMain contentMain = mData.get(position);
        holder.myContent= mData.get(position).getMyContent();
}
```

Comment: Can you add ViewHolder's code?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't bind the `onClickListener` in `onCreateViewHolder`. Purpose of `onCreateViewHolder` is to construct the ViewHolder and not binding information to it.

Following code in `onCreateViewHolder`:

`final ContentMain contentMain = mData.get(viewType);`

Will always return first element because your viewType is `0`. It doesn't describe the position.

Move this code in `onBindViewHolder` as follows:

```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ContentMain contentMain = mData.get(position);
        holder.myContent= mData.get(position).getMyContent();

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), contentMain.getMyContent(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
        });    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get you data inside `onClick()`**.

You are getting data using `position` while creating `ViewHolder`. It will give wrong `position` since `recyclerview` must be calculating layout measurements -

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {

    final View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false); //Avoid inflate layout with null parent


    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ContentMain contentMain = mData.get(getAdapterPosition());
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), contentMain.getMyContent(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }    

    ViewHolder vHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vHolder;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Probably you should define click listeners inside `ViewHolder` -

```
public static ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do you stuffs here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```